# Azure git Build Service setting SSH and PAT

Tags: git, azure, service, azure-devops, ssh-keys

Azure git has the concept of a Build Service. Each project has its own build service.

If you go to Azure > click on Project > Settings > Repositories > Permissions the Build Service will be listed under Users.

I would like to use the Build Service to clone git repos, and run other git commands.

But I don't know how to assign it a public SSH key, or to assign it a Personal Access Token. Because I can't log in as the Build Service to set those things.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify if you're running Azure DevOps on-premise, or in the cloud? Is there some example pipeline code that you're looking to run?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use the Build Service to clone git repos, and run other git commands.

As far as I know, there is no method could manually create PAT(Personal Access Token) or SSH key for Build Service Account.

But you can directly use the `system.accesstoken` related to the service account in Azure Pipeline.

system.accesstoken is generated by the build service account, but it is a secret variable, we cannot get the specific content.

Here is a doc about the [system.accesstoken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken).

Here are the steps:

1. Enable the option: **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**

[image]

2:To clone the repo, you could use the following PowerShell Script:

```
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone RepoURL
```

Here is a doc about [use PAT to clone repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat).

**Note:** The build service account needs to have sufficient permissions to operate the repo.